# Is the problem of evaluating a boolean formula on a given assignment P-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

I know that the CIRCUIT VALUE problem is P-complete.
In the CIRCUIT VALUE problem the input is a Boolean circuit together with an input to this circuit, and the answer is the evaluation of the given circuit on the given input.

I wish to know if the problem of evaluating a Boolean formula on a given assignment is also P-complete. From one hand, it seems that a Boolean circuit and a Boolean formula are very similar objects. Also, the proof of that CIRCUIT VALUE is P-complete results from the Cook-Levin problem, the same theorem that actually shows that SAT is NP-Complete, so I don't see a reason why this problem won't be P-Complete.
From the other hand, it seems pretty easy to evaluate a Boolean formula in logarithmic space, so if this problem is indeed P-complete I think it would imply L = P which is unknown.

So I think I'm missing something.. any ideas people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is apparently the same as the "boolean formula value problem" similar to the "boolean sentence value problem" (BSVP) proven to be in ALOGTIME by Buss-Cook-Gupta-Ramachandran. an improved algorithm and refs are given in [Algorithms for Boolean Formula Evaluation and
for Tree Contraction](http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/Boolean3/paper.pdf) by Buss.

Answer (score 8):

In his 1987 paper "[The Boolean formula value problem is in ALOGTIME](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/28395.28409)", Buss showed that Boolean formula evaluation is in ALOGTIME (alternating logarithmic time), which is a uniform version of NC<sup>1</sup> and so probably smaller than P. It is also ALOGTIME-complete under AC<sup>0</sup> reductions.

Comment: so does it mean that Boolean formula evaluation is not P-complete?

Comment: We don't know that for sure, but that's probably correct.